# Sublime Text 3 - Sublime Linter 3 - Why isn't "HTML Tidy" working?

Tags: html, windows-xp, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, package-control

I'm a brand new coder trying to wean myself off of the Codecademy web environment. I'm using Sublime Text 3 in tandem with Sublime Linter 3 in order to approximate the real-time error-checking to which I've become accustomed from Codecademy's site.

I know that each linter needs to be installed separately in ST3 and I've successfully integrated "csslint" and "jshint". Both work properly.

Now, I'm trying to get an html linter to error-check my html code and I can only seem to find "HTML Tidy", which I have installed via package control. Unlike the aforementioned linters, which simply require a pre-defined command line string for input at terminal, online tutorials have me installing "HTML tidy" via a winrar executable.

Now I am regrouping and would greatly appreciate any feedback you can provide that might move me incrementally closer to having a working HTML linter. I am using a windows xp computer. Many kind thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Installation Instructions for the plugin, there is a Windows binary for Tidy available [here](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?HTML_Tidy_for_Windows).

For some background, Tidy is a command line tool that comes pre-installed with Mac and Linux but not Windows. Downloading the binary mentioned [here](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?HTML_Tidy_for_Windows) and placing it in your path will allow it to be run. To check where it should be placed, run `echo %path%` from the command line.

Once that is there it will work. To see the available arguments to be run with Tidy, run `tidy -help` from the command line. These arguments can be added to `"args"` linter settings.

Comment: You can find the plugin installation instructions [here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-html-tidy)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy `tiny.exe` to folder `C:\Windows\System32\`, and restart ST3.